# Cobertura Plugin Missing in SonarQube 7.0

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops, cobertura

I am using community Edition of SonarQube v7.0 . I am trying to get Cobertura code coverage results from my Jenkins Job. Cobertura and SonarQube are configured correctly in Jenkins. I can see the sonar results in my sonar local host but not the Cobertura code coverage results. I looked up and found the Cobertura-Sonar Plugin in Plugin Library (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library)
But, when i search in Sonarqube as an admin at Administration-> MarketPlace, I don't see the plugin.

How can I get the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Plugin Version Matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix), the Cobertura plugin isn't compatible beyond SonarQube 6.0. There were API changes in 6.1 that the Cobertura plugin was never updated to address.

Comment: Thanks G. Ann. I was unable to find that and then moved on using jaCoCo which is doing the code coverage.

Comment: @newdevopsguy please accept the answer if it solved your problem.